# Renaming a sheet based of specific words in a cell

Tags: vba

I want to make a macro that will take the value in a cell and rename the sheet using this value. I only want a part the cell value to be used as the sheet name.

For example, in cell A1, it says "John Doe"... I want the macro to name that sheet "Doe, J.". How would I do that?

I already know how to name the sheet based off the entire cell.

```
Sub RenameSheet()    
    Dim rs As Worksheet
    For Each rs In Sheets
        rs.Name = rs.Range("B5")
    Next rs    
End Sub
```

Comment: What if you have two names that have the same last name and first initial? For example: `John Doe` and `Jane Doe`.  Then it would try to name both sheets `Doe, J.` which would cause an error.

Comment: Though technical concerns aside, this line of code should work for you: `rs.Name = Split(rs.Range("B5").Value, " ")(1) & ", " & Left(Split(rs.Range("B5").Value)(0), 1) & "."`

Comment: Im not worried about having the same last name at this point, but i do see your concern about that

Comment: And it worked so you are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string with the name first, and hence check if the sheet exists already (if so, adding a counter and make sure you don't name two sheets with the same name). Something like this:

```
Sub RenameSheet()

'VARIABLES DECLARATION
Dim rs As Worksheet
Dim new_name As String, tmp_new_name As String
Dim counter As Integer: counter = 0
Dim counter1 As Integer: counter1 = 1
Dim allNames As Object

'CODE
Set allNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each rs In Sheets
    'FIRST, LET'S PARSE THE NAME "LAST NAME" + ", " + "NAME INITIAL" + "."  
    new_name = Split(rs.Range("B5"), " ")(1) + ", " + Left(Split(rs.Range("B5"), " ")(0), 1) + "."
    'CHECK IF IT EXISTS
    If allNames.Exists(new_name) Then
        'ADD A COUNTER "(N)" UNTIL IT DOESN'T EXIST ANYMORE
        tmp_new_name = new_name
        Do While allNames.Exists(tmp_new_name) <> False
            tmp_new_name = new_name & " (" & counter1 & ")"
            counter1 = counter1 + 1
        Loop
        counter1 = 1
        new_name = tmp_new_name
    End If
    'RENAME
    rs.name = new_name
    counter = counter + 1
    'KEEP THE NAME STORED IN MEMORY (INTO THE DICTIONARY)
    allNames.Add rs.name, counter
Next rs
End Sub
```